# Dart: const class or const var?

Tags: flutter, class, dart, var

Newb question.
For performance, there's much difference between the **class** below (widget to build TextField),
or a **const** that doesn't rebuild anything? I heard in Flutter as everything are widgets, when building for example **func vs class**, always build a class to replace whatever you are building on your code. I thought this could be the same.

```
class RoundedBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const RoundedBox({
    this.text,
    this.onChanged,
  });
  final String text;
  final Function onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      onChanged: onChanged,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: text,
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 1.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or just a simple const var?:

```
const kTextFieldDecoration = InputDecoration(
  hintText: 'Enter a value',
  hintStyle: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.grey,
  ),
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
  border: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
  ),
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 1.0),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
  ),
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 2.0),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you will get better performance if you reuse the `InputDecoration` defined as const.

But this is equivalent(notice the const before InputDecoration). It's a good practice to use `const` for `Widgets` that does not change.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      onChanged: onChanged,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        hintText: text,
        hintStyle: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 1.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 2.0),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @YoBo. I suppose as usual that everything depends on what we need to know the best ways.